# Which is a better way to combine multiple LiveData(s): using MediatorLiveData or switchMap?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, switchmap, mediatorlivedata

Which approach is more recommended to combine multiple LiveData(s): using `MediatorLiveData` or `switchMap`?

```
// MediatorLiveData approach
fun <A, B, C> combine(
    liveData1: LiveData<A>,
    liveData2: LiveData<B>,
    onChanged: (A?, B?) -> C
): MediatorLiveData<C> {
    return MediatorLiveData<C>().apply {
        addSource(liveData1) {
            value = onChanged(liveData1.value, liveData2.value)
        }
        addSource(liveData2) {
            value = onChanged(liveData1.value, liveData2.value)
        }
    }
}

// switchMap approach
fun <A, B, C> combine(
    liveData1: LiveData<A>,
    liveData2: LiveData<B>,
    onChanged: (A, B) -> C
): LiveData<C> {
    return liveData1.switchMap { a ->
        liveData2.map { b ->
            onChanged(a, b)
        }
    }
}
```

The `MediatorLiveData` approach may be more common but the `switchMap` approach looks simpler. Both approaches seem to serve the same purpose in many cases.

Comment: when you want to combine more than 2 livedata mediator is better solution, also in mediator you can add more features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `MediatorLiveData` directly.

All [`Transformations.`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations) are actually `MediatorLiveData`s - `switchMap` is just a mediator that dynamically swaps source depending on return value of provided `switchMapFunction`.

Second approach just generates useless overhead - you allocate `switchMap` `MediatorLiveData` that keeps creating and swapping in new `map` `MediatorLiveData` objects whenever `liveData1` changes.